# Is there an equivalent of @@rowcount for local scope of a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there an equivalent of `@@RowCount` available in SQL Server that tracks the modified/inserted/deleted rows for the local scope of a stored procedure? I'm thinking of something similar to the behavior of `@@identity` vs `scope_identity()` but for row counts.

Link to a discussion on the identity's mentioned above:
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Comment: It's important to know recently generated identity value to use it in another tables so it was implemented. While nobody cares about total rows affected by session, so it was NOT implemented

Comment: I am trying to migrate data based off generated scripts.  The way the scripts are generated is one insert at a time.  I am then splitting up the scripts into batches to execute.  I know there are better tools to do this but I have to work around organizational hurdles.  It's not feasible for me to put a @@Rowcount after all the 1000s of inserts so I was hoping to get the row count affected per batch.

Comment: Also I'm surprised this isn't a more common occurrence, I could see myself encountering this situation again in the future at a different company/job. 
 "Nobody cares" is a pretty broad statement in programming and not really in the spirit of the forum..

Comment: You have your answer. There is no equivalent, no shortcut. And to be honest, I don't think this approach is useful. Migration scripts tend to do more than just simple inserts, so accumulating the @@rowcount value for every statement would not generate an accurate number. Perhaps it would be easier to just count the rows in all the affected tables after the script runs. Search the internet if that seems like it might fulfill your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement it using variable:

```
DELCARE @row_count INT = 0;

-- DML INSERT/MERGE/UPDATE/DELETE
SET @row_count += @@rowcount;

-- DML INSERT/MERGE/UPDATE/DELETE
SET @row_count += @@rowcount;


PRINT @row_count;
```

---

For migration script I would simply use `OUTPUT INTO` approach and log interesting informations:

```
CREATE TABLE a(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), i INT);
CREATE TABLE log(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), creation_date DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(),
                      operation VARCHAR(20), table_name VARCHAR(20), id_ INT);

INSERT INTO a(i)
OUTPUT 'INSERT', 'a', inserted.id
INTO log(operation, table_name, id_)
VALUES (10)
;

UPDATE a
SET i = 10
OUTPUT 'UPDATE','a', inserted.id
INTO log(operation, table_name, id_);

DELETE FROM a
OUTPUT 'DELETE','a', deleted.id
INTO log(operation, table_name, id_);

SELECT *
FROM log;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/FTSA7611)**

After migration is over you could simply make aggregation using `COUNT`. It will give you more information about what happened than simple `@@rowcount`.

Comment: This is normally what I would do  but I am working off auto generated data migration scripts that generate one insert at a time.  This would be infeasible to add this line after each insert for 1000's of rows of data.

Comment: Marked this as answer, the real answer is no there is nothing that does this but this is the best work around.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `@@rowcount` does not work correctly for local scope?  I did a quick test to see if it was affected by triggers, and it appears not to be:

```
create table test (x int not null)
create table test_1 (y int not null)
trigger dbo.test_ins on dbo.test after insert as insert into test_1 values (5), (6)
insert into test values (1)
select @@rowcount
           1
select count(*) from ed_test_1
           2
```

That's the behaviour I would want: even though the insert has caused 2 rows to be inserted in some other table, via the trigger, the `@@rowcount` value is the count inserted into the main table.  This differs from `@@identity`, which is mucked up by triggers:

```
create table test (x int not null identity, x1 int not null)
create table test_1 (y int not null identity, y1 int not null)
create trigger dbo.test_ins on dbo.test after insert as insert into test_1 (y1) values (5), (6)
insert into test (x1) values (1)
select @@identity
    2
insert into test (x1) values (2)
select @@identity
    4
```

Here, `@@identity` refers to whatever the trigger did, not the main insert I was asking for.  So while I agree that `@@identity` should be avoided, and `scope_identity()` or an `output` clause used instead, I don't see that the same reasons exist to avoid `@@rowcount`.

```
select @@version
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU12) (KB4536648) - 13.0.5698.0 (X64)
...
```